# Capture audio that playing from browser and send to LEX PostContent API

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio-recording, web-audio-api, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

We are working on web application with amazon connect, Here amazon connect playing audio response that we need to 
capture from browser and send it AWS Javascript LEX Post Content API.

We used following sample application as reference and worked with microphone, but its not capturing audio response that amazon connect playing audio response.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/ 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-browser-audio-capture

Please help me, how can we record audio response from amazon connect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about JavaScript app that is integrated with Amazon Connect's softphone via the Amazon Connect Streams API (https://github.com/aws/amazon-connect-streams). Streams lets you do call control and change agent status, but does not give you access to the underlying media of an Amazon Connect contact. The Amazon Connect RTC JavaScript library (https://github.com/aws/connect-rtc-js/blob/master/test/unit/rtc_session.js) may be a better fit for your application as it exposes the underlying WebRTC media resources